# Loop through an array and set the value of any html inputs that match the array values

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, match

I'm trying to find the most efficient way of looping through an array of strings, and then click a corresponding checkbox input that matches any of the values found within the array.

I came up with the below, which works, but I think there's probably a more efficient solution.  Anyone have any tips to help me clean this up?

```
<script>
    var comodArr = ['Gold','Copper'];
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#setfilters").click(function() {
            <!-- Commodities -->
            if(jQuery.inArray("Gold", comodArr) !== -1) {
                jQuery('li[val="Gold"] input').click();
            }
            if(jQuery.inArray("Silver", comodArr) !== -1) {
                jQuery('li[val="Silver"] input').click();
            }
            if(jQuery.inArray("Copper", comodArr) !== -1) {
                jQuery('li[val="Copper"] input').click();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="setfilters" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down">&nbsp;</i> Set Filters</a>
```

Updated code after answer below.  Much better!

```
<script>
    var fieldVals = ['Gold', 'Copper'];
    var fieldValArr = fieldVals.split(', ');
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#setfilters").click(function() {
            fieldValArr.forEach(fieldVal => jQuery("li[val='" + fieldVal + "'] input").click());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to undo this if user changes filters?

Comment: Not sure if it's needed.  What's your thought there? The array is established dynamically on page load.  It's meant to be a button that pre-sets filters based on the user's known db stored interests.

Comment: Hard to make suggestions without knowing how the UI needs to work

Comment: Well, if it wasn't obvious I'm manipulating a pre-existing UI to achieve a usability outcome that wasn't intended by the developer.  I'm detecting values of "my" interests and checking inputs to achieve a quick filtered result.  One could still use the current UI to select/de-select as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array.

```js
comodArr.forEach(comod => jQuery(`li[val="${comod}"] input`).click());
```

BTW, you shouldn't add nonstandard attributes like `val` to elements. If you need to add your own attributes, use `data-XXX`, e.g. `data-val="Gold"`

Comment: Perfect!  Much appreciated.  Not my code I'm manipulating but agreed on nonstandard attrs on elements.